# Default value from a list not passed to the next page while using <p:selectOneMenu> in jsf datatable

Tags: jsf

Default value from a list not passed to the next page while using  in jsf datatable,all the default values get replaced with null value for all the items not selected in the datatable

Comment: Im new to jsf so i used something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the list using the managedbean in session scope.

Comment: I can help you better if you can post your code too.

Answer (score 0):

### Heading ##

```
                        <!--    <h:outputText value="#{rule.userAlertCategory.label}"/> -->
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="catCombo" value="#{rule.userAlertCategory}" style = "width:100%" converter="srUserAlertCategorySelectItemsConverter">
                            <p:ajax event="change" update="subCatCombo" listener="#{newAlertSetupController.onCategoryChanged}" process="@this"/>
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{newAlertSetupController.userAlertCategoryList}" var="cat" itemLabel="#{cat.label}" itemValue="#{cat}"/>

                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
```

Comment: If you take value from one page and want it in next page, you have to make an http session and pass the whole object to the next page.

Comment: when i use  itemValue="#{cat.label}"&value="#{rule.userAlertCategory.label}" all the selected values from the list appears on the selectOneMenu,but this does not happen when i use itemValue="#{cat}"&value="#{rule.userAlertCategory}" only the first value from the list appears